# Producing constant constant electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Can we create constant electric field using varying magnetic field?

And also ,
How the varying magnetic field give rise to varying electric field not a constant electric field .

Answer (score 2):

If you could arrange for the current in a solenoid to increase at a constant rate, then the rate of change of the flux of the magnetic field and the induced (circular) electric field in and around the solenoid would be constant (but not uniform). If the rate of change of the flux is not constant, then the E field will not be constant.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered by Maxwell's equations. One of these equations states that
the time derivative of a magnetic field generates an electric field,
$\frac{dB}{dt} \propto E
$. Hence, if we change the magnetic field we generate an electric field. If the change of the magnetic field is constant, the electric field is constant.